# Accepting an answer on question closed as duplicates

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, etiquette, duplicate-answers

At the risk of having two questions closed as duplicates in the space of an hour -
I asked a question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525811/asp-net-mvc-syntax), it has been closed as exact duplicate. [Embarrassing but I think understandable given the titles/content]
Three people answered it with correct answers (they concur with the answers on the original).
Should I accept the best one?

Searching this site I found plenty of questions about whether it should be possible or not - I suppose I am asking about etiquette.

Is it rude if I don't accept an answer - considering they spent time answering my question?

Comment: I have answered 42 different questions, and more that were deleted, and only got 3 accepted answers. To many of the truly helpful, an accepted answer matters little. We only care about getting out information that would help people, but many of us want confirmation that we actually helped (usually found in the form of comments, accepting answers and/or upvotes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should absolutely accept an answer if there was one that answered your question.  Closed status has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Accepting as answer as it was first and tells me that it is okay to accept an answer on a closed question

Answer (score 2):

If you received answers and think one of them was really helpful and maybe even solved the issue, then you can accept it.

But accepting an answer or not is in general totally up to you.